# How to make list items clickable so as to redirect user to their specific different pages without making different page for each item

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I have created a list view of items in my app, and now I want the items to be clickable so that each item redirects the user to their respective page. What will be the easier way to do this without making a different page for each item on the list? Here's the code for the list which picks up data from json format.

```
Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
// scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: cryptoData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 16, 0),
                              height: 100,
                              width: double.maxFinite,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                elevation: 5,
                                child: Container(
                                  
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 5, top: 5),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Row(
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        cryptoIcon(
                                                            cryptoData[index]),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 10,
                                                        ),
                                                        // Spacer(),
                                                        cryptoChange(
                                                            cryptoData[index]),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 10,
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 20,
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ))
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),

Widget cryptoIcon(data) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
      child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('${data['image']}'),
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget cryptoChange(data) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: '${data['change']}',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Raleway",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 35, 93),
              fontSize: 14),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
                text: '\n${data['changeValue']}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 35, 93),
                  fontSize: 12,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is that store data used in each list view element/tile as an object and pass that data to next page. You'll design page once and it will appear with new data every time you click different list view element/tile. If you can share code I can answer more accurately.

Comment: Sure i'll edit the question